# Asynchronous Serial I/O on Win32 -- How To Create An Alert Event

Tags: c, asynchronous, winapi

I tried following Allen Denver's [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms810467(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to implement asynchronous serial port I/O. What isn't mentioned in the article is how or where to call the functions in a main program loop in a useful manner. After putting them in a loop that comes back every second, it was clear there should be no need to call the ReadFile() periodically. I tried putting a WaitCommEvent() in the loop so the read would only occur if characters arrived at the port. That caused a cascade of errors. In trying to simplify the code into something I could post here, even my attempts to open the file in OVERLAPPED mode started failing, so I can't seem to post a useful example. However, I will post something similar with the basic notion that I don't really care if the reads and writes have to be synchronous if I can simply trigger them with an asynchronous event like characters showing up on the serial port. The asynchronous functions from Allen Denver's article are quite involved, and it's not clear to me from his examples how to trigger a read on characters arriving at the port.

In the following code there are five lines commented out in the body of the while(1) loop where I was trying to wait for the characters to arrive. The WaitCommEvent() errors appeared to cite pending I/O even though the port was opened in overlap mode (in the original code), and both the send and receive functions had their own OVERLAPPED structures. What is the proper way to resolve this?

```
/* WINSIO.c                                                        2020-01-22 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int ConfigureSerialPort(HANDLE hPort)
{
  int Status;
  DCB dcb = {0};
  COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;

  dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);

  Status = GetCommTimeouts(hPort, &timeouts);
  GetCommTimeouts(hPort, &timeouts);
  timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout          = 50;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant     = 50;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier   = 50;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant    = 50;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 10;
  if (!SetCommTimeouts(hPort, &timeouts)) {
    printf("Error setting timeouts on port!\n");
  }

  Status = GetCommState(hPort, &dcb);
  dcb.BaudRate =          19200;
  dcb.Parity =            NOPARITY;
  dcb.fBinary =           TRUE;             // Binary mode; no EOF check 
  dcb.fParity =           FALSE;            // Enable parity checking 
  dcb.fOutxCtsFlow =      FALSE;            // No CTS output flow control 
  dcb.fOutxDsrFlow =      FALSE;            // No DSR output flow control 
  dcb.fDtrControl =       DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE; // DTR flow control type 
  dcb.fDsrSensitivity =   FALSE;            // DSR sensitivity 
  dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = FALSE;            // XOFF continues Tx 
  dcb.fOutX =             FALSE;            // No XON/XOFF out flow control 
  dcb.fInX =              FALSE;            // No XON/XOFF in flow control
  dcb.fErrorChar =        FALSE;            // Disable error replacement 
  dcb.fNull =             FALSE;            // Disable null stripping 
  dcb.fRtsControl =       RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE; // RTS flow control 
  dcb.fAbortOnError =     FALSE;            // Do not abort reads/writes on err
  dcb.ByteSize =          8;                // Number of bits/byte, 4-8 
  dcb.StopBits =          ONESTOPBIT;       // 0,1,2 = 1, 1.5, 2
  dcb.EvtChar =           0x84;             // 'T' 

  if (!SetCommState (hPort, &dcb)) {
    printf("Unable to configure serial port!\n");
  }
  return 0;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int sendpckt(HANDLE hComm, unsigned length, unsigned char * pckt)
{
    unsigned long NbytesWritten = 0;
    int result;
    DWORD dwCommEvent;
    OVERLAPPED oWrite;

    oWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (oWrite.hEvent == NULL)
      return FALSE; // Error creating overlapped event handle.

    result = WriteFile(hComm, pckt, length, &NbytesWritten, NULL);
    //result = WriteFile(hComm, pckt, length, &NbytesWritten, &oWrite);

    if (!result) printf("Err: %d\n", GetLastError());
    WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwCommEvent, &oWrite);

//    printf("Wrote? %d:%d\n", result, NbytesWritten);
    CloseHandle(oWrite.hEvent);
    return 0;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int recvpckt(HANDLE hComm, unsigned char * pckt)
{
  int Status, idx = 0, len = 0;
  unsigned long Nbytes;
  unsigned char chRead;
  OVERLAPPED oRead;

    do {
      //Status = ReadFile(hComm, &chRead, 1, &Nbytes, &oRead);
      Status = ReadFile(hComm, &chRead, 1, &Nbytes, NULL);
      if (Status) {
      pckt[idx++] = chRead;
      if(Nbytes > 0) len = idx;
       }
      }
     while(Nbytes > 0);
  return len;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int args(int argc, char * argv[], char * port) 
{
  static int i;
  i = atoi(argv[1]);
  sprintf(port, "\\\\.\\COM%d", i);
  return i;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  HANDLE hPort;
  int result, len, Status;
  DWORD dwCommEvent;
  OVERLAPPED o;
  unsigned idx = 0;
  unsigned char TXBUF[] = "T", RXBUF[2048], port[64];

  if (argc > 1) result = args(argc, argv, port);
   SetConsoleTitle(port); // To specify serial port number on open 
  hPort = CreateFile (port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
                       //OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL); 
                       OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); 

  ConfigureSerialPort(hPort);
    if (hPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
     printf("Error in openning serial port\n");
     exit(0); // No point in going on if serial port didn't open
     }
    else
     printf("Serial Port Open\n");

    Status = SetCommMask(hPort, EV_RXCHAR);
  if (Status == FALSE) printf("Error! Setting CommMask\n");

  o.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
  if (o.hEvent == NULL) printf("Error creating overlapped event; abort.\n");

  while (1) {

    sendpckt(hPort, 1, TXBUF);
    printf("Sending 0x%.2X\n", TXBUF[0]);

//  Status = WaitCommEvent(hPort, &dwCommEvent, &o); // Wait for chars
//  if (Status == FALSE)
//    printf("Error Setting WaitCommEvent()%d\n", GetLastError());
//  else { // If WaitCommEvent() == TRUE then Read the received data 

//    printf("Chars Recveived\n");  
    len = recvpckt(hPort, RXBUF);
    if (len > 0) 
    {
    printf("RCVD(%d): ", len);
    }

  for (idx=0; idx<len; idx++)
   {
    printf("%d:0x%.2X ", idx+1, RXBUF[idx]);
   }

//    }
    SleepEx(1000, TRUE); // How often to look for data in RX buffer
  }
  CloseHandle(o.hEvent); // Close the Event Handle
  CloseHandle(hPort); // Close the serial port
}
```

Posting additional code after much appreciated feedback from Rita Han. What was clear from the other posts was my Synchronous example didn't get the point across. So I'm attaching the asynchronous version that mostly works, but leaves much to be desired. If it could be simplified to the length of Rita Han's example, that would be fantastic. This example does "function" meaning that it both sends and receives. The problem is, as originally stated, it requires polling the ports periodically for characters present, and that is a super huge drag. The following code is a nearly identical recreation of Allen Denver's code, and it does not provide the event based response I'm looking for, but it does send and receive chars. I am currently running it across a null modem cable with two serial ports, so the behavior is quite easy to observe. The reliance on polling the serial port is clear by changing the timeout value on the SleepEX() statement. As useful as Rita Han's feedback was, the code did not exhibit the behavior I'm looking for. If someone can take the following example, and make it respond to characters arriving at the serial port rather than waiting to get polled, that is what I'm looking for. Do I need to use ReadFileEX()? Is there some other way to register an event that needs to get mixed in here? Joseph M. Newcomer discounts all use of serial events in this [article](http://www.flounder.com/serial.htm) saying they only exist for 16 bit windows compatibility, and then goes on to provide a substantially more convoluted example of how to program a serial port than Allen Denver did. Does it really need to be this difficult?

```
/* WINAIO.c                                                        2020-01-22 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int ConfigureSerialPort(HANDLE hPort) {
  int Status;
  DCB dcb = {0};
  COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;

  dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);

  Status = GetCommTimeouts(hPort, & timeouts);
  GetCommTimeouts(hPort, & timeouts);
  timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 50;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
  if (!SetCommTimeouts(hPort, & timeouts)) {
    printf("Error setting timeouts on port!\n");
  }

  Status = GetCommState(hPort, & dcb);
  dcb.BaudRate = 19200;
  dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
  dcb.fBinary = TRUE; // Binary mode; no EOF check 
  dcb.fParity = FALSE; // Enable parity checking 
  dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE; // No CTS output flow control 
  dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE; // No DSR output flow control 
  dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE; // DTR flow control type 
  dcb.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE; // DSR sensitivity 
  dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = FALSE; // XOFF continues Tx 
  dcb.fOutX = FALSE; // No XON/XOFF out flow control 
  dcb.fInX = FALSE; // No XON/XOFF in flow control
  dcb.fErrorChar = FALSE; // Disable error replacement 
  dcb.fNull = FALSE; // Disable null stripping 
  dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE; // RTS flow control 
  dcb.fAbortOnError = FALSE; // Do not abort reads/writes on err
  dcb.ByteSize = 8; // Number of bits/byte, 4-8 
  dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; // 0,1,2 = 1, 1.5, 2
  dcb.EvtChar = 0x84; // 'T' 

  if (!SetCommState(hPort, & dcb)) {
    printf("Unable to configure serial port!\n");
  }
  return 0;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int sendpckt(HANDLE hComm, unsigned length, unsigned char *pckt) {
  unsigned long NbytesWritten = 0;
  OVERLAPPED ovl = {0};
  BOOL fRes;

  ovl.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
  if (ovl.hEvent == NULL)
    return FALSE; // Error creating overlapped event handle.

  //Issue Write.
  if (!WriteFile(hComm, pckt, length, & NbytesWritten, & ovl)) {
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
      fRes = FALSE; // WriteFile failed, but isn't delayed. Report error...
    } else {
      //Write is pending.
      if (!GetOverlappedResult(hComm, & ovl, & NbytesWritten, TRUE))
        fRes = FALSE;
      else
        fRes = TRUE;
    }
  } else // Write operation completed successfully.
    fRes = TRUE;
  //    printf(" 0X%.2X ", chWrite);
  CloseHandle(ovl.hEvent);
  return fRes;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int recvpckt(HANDLE hComm, unsigned char *pckt) {
  # define READ_TIMEOUT 500 // milliseconds
  int len = 0;
  unsigned long Nbytes;
  unsigned char chRead, BUF[2048];
  BOOL fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
  OVERLAPPED ovl = {0};
  DWORD dwRes;

  /*
  Status = SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXFLAG);
  if (Status == FALSE) printf("Error! Setting CommMask\n");
//  else                 printf("Setting CommMask Succesful\n");
//  */

  ovl.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
  if (ovl.hEvent == NULL) printf("Error creating overlapped event; abort.\n");

  if (!fWaitingOnRead) {
    // Issue read operation
    if (!ReadFile(hComm, & BUF, 2048, & Nbytes, & ovl))
    //if(!ReadFile(hComm, &chRead, 1, &Nbytes, &ovl))
    {
      if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) // read not delayed?
        // Error in communications; report it
        printf("Error in Communications...\n");
      else {
        fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
        //   printf("l:%d ", len); // shows loop alive
      }
    } else {
      if (Nbytes > 0) {
        // read completed immediately
        memcpy(pckt, BUF, Nbytes);
        len = Nbytes;
        printf("Immediate Read Completion\n");
        //HandleASuccessfulRead(lpbuf, dwRead);
      }
    }
  }
  if (fWaitingOnRead) {
    dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(ovl.hEvent, READ_TIMEOUT);
    switch (dwRes) {
      // Read completed.
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
      if (!GetOverlappedResult(hComm, & ovl, & Nbytes, FALSE))
        printf("Error in Communications Lower Portion\n");
      // Error in communications; report it.
      else {
        if (Nbytes > 0) {
          // Read completed successfully
          // HandleASuccessfulRead(lpbuf, dwRead);
          // Will run away and execute here every time
          fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
          memcpy(pckt, BUF, Nbytes);
          len = Nbytes;
          printf("Read Completion After Wait\n");
        }
      }
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
      //printf("l:%d %d\n", len,rxstate);
      // Operation isn't complete yet. fWaitingOnRead flag isn't changed
      // since I'll loop back around, and I don't want to issue another read
      // until the first one finishes.
      // Good time to do some background work.
      break;

    default:
      // Error in the WaitForSingleObject; abort.
      // This indicates a problem with the OVERLAPPED structure's event handle
      break;
    }
  }
  CloseHandle(ovl.hEvent);
  return Nbytes;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int args(int argc, char *argv[], char *port) {
  static int i;
  i = atoi(argv[1]);
  sprintf(port, "\\\\.\\COM%d", i);
  return i;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  HANDLE hPort;
  int result, len, Status;
  DWORD dwCommEvent;
  OVERLAPPED o;
  unsigned idx = 0;
  unsigned char TXBUF[] = "T", RXBUF[2048], port[64];

  if (argc > 1) result = args(argc, argv, port);
  SetConsoleTitle(port); // To specify serial port number on open 
  hPort = CreateFile(port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
  //OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); 

  ConfigureSerialPort(hPort);
  if (hPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Error in openning serial port\n");
    exit(0); // No point in going on if serial port didn't open
  } else
    printf("Serial Port Open\n");

  Status = SetCommMask(hPort, EV_RXCHAR);
  if (Status == FALSE) printf("Error! Setting CommMask\n");

  o.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
  if (o.hEvent == NULL) printf("Error creating overlapped event; abort.\n");

  while (1) { // This is the loop for getting work done.

    sendpckt(hPort, 1, TXBUF);
    printf("Sending 0x%.2X\n", TXBUF[0]);

    //  Status = WaitCommEvent(hPort, &dwCommEvent, &o); // Wait for chars
    //  if (Status == FALSE)
    //    printf("Error Setting WaitCommEvent()%d\n", GetLastError());
    //  else { // If WaitCommEvent() == TRUE then Read the received data 

    //    printf("Chars Recveived\n");  
    len = recvpckt(hPort, RXBUF);
    if (len > 0) {
      printf("RCVD(%d): ", len);
    }

    for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
      printf("%d:0x%.2X ", idx + 1, RXBUF[idx]);
    }

    //    }
    SleepEx(1000, TRUE); // How often to look for data in RX buffer
    // And how often to send data to the other port
  }
  CloseHandle(o.hEvent); // Close the Event Handle
  CloseHandle(hPort); // Close the serial port
}
```

Comment: for what you need asynchronous I/O ? and use event - wort way from 3 possible for get notify when I/O complete

Comment: Do you mind formatting your text so it's more easily readable?

Comment: and `OVERLAPPED` must be valid until I/O active. as result if you declare it as local variable in function - you can not exit from function until I/O active. in general you must never user local vars for `OVERLAPPED`

Comment: The *ONLY* reason I need OVERLAPPED I/O is to prevent the ReadFile() from blocking all other operations while waiting for data to arrive. Otherwise I have to constantly poll the port for data. A WaitCommEvent() blocks execution if executed as non-Overlapped which rules it out as well.

Comment: @KyleG - asynchronous - this is event based programming. for this you need absolute another code structure. you begin I/O and not wait when it finished. instead you have thread(s), which wait for events (user input, apc, iocp packets) and do action based on event. and better use apc or iocp on file instead event in overlapped.

Comment: Rita Han's example absolute wrong in all

Comment: @KyleG You can create a new thread which is in charge of for IO reading/writing so that the main thread will be able to continue to execute. And check IO complete status in main thread.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I put your edited example into a sample application (the one I edited and posted,) and compiled it. It runs, and does effectively what I'm looking for, but randomly exits for no apparent reason. Maybe it's a timeout, I don't know. I'm not sure if I should be using ReadFileEX() and WriteFileEX() instead. The recvpckt() function you provided definitely wakes up on receipt of a character because I set the SleepEX() to 10 seconds, and sent from another port. Sure enough, it wakes up and receives it. So the structure of that code appears to do the job.

Comment: @KyleGk You can share related code which randomly exits for no apparent reason so I can check it.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Okay. How do I do that? Do I need to upload it to GitHub, or can I add a new segment here somewhere?

Comment: @KyleG If your initial alert event issue solved you can accept the answer and post a new question about "randomly exits" issue with reproducible code. Post code in question body is more convenient for checking by others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open serial port with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) if you want to write and read asynchronously.
- For `lpNumberOfBytesRead` parameter in `ReadFile`: Use **`NULL`** for this parameter if this is an asynchronous operation to avoid potentially erroneous results. You can check read length via `InternalHigh` of [OVERLAPPED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-overlapped#remarks).
- `ReadFile` and [`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) may result in an error code `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, it is not a failure; it designates the write operation is pending completion asynchronously.

The following is an example you can refer to:

```
int sendpckt(HANDLE hComm, unsigned length, unsigned char * pckt)
{
    BOOL result;
    DWORD dwCommEvent;
    OVERLAPPED oWrite = { 0 };
    DWORD errCode;

    result = SetCommMask(hComm, EV_TXEMPTY);
    if (!result) printf("Err: %d\n", GetLastError());

    result = WriteFile(hComm, pckt, length, NULL, &oWrite);
    if (result == FALSE)
    {
        errCode = GetLastError();

        if (errCode != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            printf("Error! Setting CommMask\n");
    }

    OVERLAPPED commOverlapped = { 0 };

    commOverlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (commOverlapped.hEvent == NULL)
        return FALSE; // Error creating overlapped event handle.

    assert(commOverlapped.hEvent);

    result = WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwCommEvent, &commOverlapped);
    if (!dwCommEvent)
        printf("Error Setting WaitCommEvent()%d\n", GetLastError());
    else
    {
        // If WaitCommEvent() == TRUE then Read the received data 
        if (dwCommEvent & EV_TXEMPTY)
        {
            printf("Send complete.\n");
        }

    }

    CloseHandle(oWrite.hEvent);
    CloseHandle(commOverlapped.hEvent);

    return 0;
};
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int recvpckt(HANDLE hComm, unsigned char * pckt)
{
    BOOL result;
    int len = 0;
    OVERLAPPED oRead = { 0 };
    DWORD errCode;
    DWORD dwCommEvent;

    result = SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR);
    if (!result) printf("Err: %d\n", GetLastError());

    result = ReadFile(hComm, pckt, 2048, NULL, &oRead);
    if (result == FALSE)
    {
        errCode = GetLastError();

        if (errCode != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            printf("nError! Setting CommMask\n");
    }

    OVERLAPPED commOverlapped = { 0 };

    commOverlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (commOverlapped.hEvent == NULL)
        return FALSE; // Error creating overlapped event handle.

    assert(commOverlapped.hEvent);

    result = WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwCommEvent, &commOverlapped);
    if (!dwCommEvent)
        printf("Error Setting WaitCommEvent()%d\n", GetLastError());
    else
    {
        if (dwCommEvent & EV_TXEMPTY)
        {
            printf("Chars Recveived\n");
            len = oRead.InternalHigh;
        }

    }

    CloseHandle(oRead.hEvent);
    CloseHandle(commOverlapped.hEvent);

    return len;
};

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    HANDLE hPort;
    int len;
    unsigned idx = 0;
    unsigned char TXBUF[] = "T", RXBUF[2048], port[64] = "COM8";

    SetConsoleTitle(port); // To specify serial port number on open 
    hPort = CreateFile(port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL); 

    ConfigureSerialPort(hPort);
    if (hPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Error in openning serial port\n");
        exit(0); // No point in going on if serial port didn't open
    }
    else
        printf("Serial Port Open\n");

    while (1) {

        sendpckt(hPort, 1, TXBUF);
        printf("Sending 0x%.2X\n", TXBUF[0]);

        len = recvpckt(hPort, RXBUF);
        if (len > 0)
        {
            printf("RCVD(%d): \n", len);
        }

        for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
        {
            printf("%d:0x%.2X \n", idx + 1, RXBUF[idx]);
        }

        SleepEx(1000, TRUE); // How often to look for data in RX buffer
    }

    CloseHandle(hPort); // Close the serial port
}
```

**Update:**

Another way is using [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) without `SetCommMask` and `WaitCommEvent`. Take read operation as an example:

```
int recvpckt(HANDLE hComm, unsigned char * pckt)
{
    BOOL result;
    int len = 0;
    OVERLAPPED oRead = { 0 };
    DWORD errCode;
    DWORD dwCommEvent;

    oRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (oRead.hEvent == NULL)
        return FALSE; // Error creating overlapped event handle.

    assert(oRead.hEvent);

    result = ReadFile(hComm, pckt, 2048, NULL, &oRead);
    if (result == FALSE)
    {
        errCode = GetLastError();

        if (errCode != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            printf("nError! Setting CommMask\n");
    }

    DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(oRead.hEvent, INFINITE);
    switch (dwWaitResult)
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        printf("Received.\n");
        break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        printf("Timeout.\n");
        break;
    case WAIT_FAILED:
        printf("Failed.\n");
        break;
    case WAIT_ABANDONED:
        printf("Abandoned.\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    CloseHandle(oRead.hEvent);

    return len;
};
```

Comment: your code full of errors. for example take only `sendpckt`. the lifetime of `oWrite` can be smaller than I/O life time which used it. you use the same `oWrite` in 2 I/O request in concurrent - again error, the overlapped must be unique per I/O request. just close `oWrite.hEvent` - but for what in this case you create it at all ?

Comment: Can you pointed out where I "use the same oWrite in 2 I/O request in concurrent"?

Comment: in `sendpckt` - you pass `&oWrite` to `WriteFile` then to `WaitCommEvent` but first -so you mix the same oWrite in 2 requests. you exit from `sendpckt` probably before I/O finished. as result when it finished  - arbitrary place in stack will be corrupted (when kernel write data to stack where was `oWrite`). event inside `oWrite` you create for what ? you not use it ! even more worst situation in `recvpckt` - you do same error with `oRead`. you use it in 2 api in concurrent. the `oRead.InternalHigh;` will be from `ReadFile` or `WaitCommEvent` ? :)

Comment: @RbMm Thanks for your kind comments. I update my answer.

Comment: what you do after update still senseless - this is not asynchronous I/O. simply open file in synchronous mode and do synchronous read/write

Answer (score 3):

Posting a complete and functional solution based on Rita Han's example:

```
/* ExAIO.c                                                         2020-02-20 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <windows.h>

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int ConfigureSerialPort(HANDLE hComm)
{
  int Status;
  DCB dcb = {0};
  COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;

  dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);

  Status = GetCommTimeouts(hComm, & timeouts);
  GetCommTimeouts(hComm, & timeouts); 
  timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout          = MAXDWORD;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier   = 0;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant     = 0;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 0;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant    = 0; 
  if (!SetCommTimeouts(hComm, & timeouts)) {
    printf("Error setting timeouts on port!\n");
  }

  Status = GetCommState(hComm, & dcb);
  dcb.BaudRate          = 19200;
  dcb.Parity            = NOPARITY;
  dcb.fBinary           = TRUE;         // Binary mode; no EOF check 
  dcb.fParity           = FALSE;        // Enable parity checking 
  dcb.fOutxCtsFlow      = FALSE;        // No CTS output flow control 
  dcb.fOutxDsrFlow      = FALSE;        // No DSR output flow control 
  dcb.fDtrControl       = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE; // DTR flow control type 
  dcb.fDsrSensitivity   = FALSE;        // DSR sensitivity 
  dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = FALSE;        // XOFF continues Tx 
  dcb.fOutX             = FALSE;        // No XON/XOFF out flow control 
  dcb.fInX              = FALSE;        // No XON/XOFF in flow control
  dcb.fErrorChar        = FALSE;        // Disable error replacement 
  dcb.fNull             = FALSE;        // Disable null stripping 
  dcb.fRtsControl       = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE; // RTS flow control 
  dcb.fAbortOnError     = FALSE;        // Do not abort reads/writes on error
  dcb.ByteSize          = 8;            // Number of bits/byte, 4-8 
  dcb.StopBits          = ONESTOPBIT;   // 0,1,2 = 1, 1.5, 2
  dcb.EvtChar           = 0x7E;         // Flag

  if (!SetCommState(hComm, & dcb)) {
    printf("Unable to configure serial port!\n");
  }
  return 0;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int sendpckt(HANDLE hComm, unsigned length, unsigned char * pckt)
{
    BOOL result;
    DWORD dwWaitResult, errCode;
    OVERLAPPED oWrite = { 0 };

    oWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (oWrite.hEvent == NULL) return FALSE; // Error creating OL event handle.

    // Initialize the rest of the OVERLAPPED structure to zero.
    oWrite.Internal     = 0;
    oWrite.InternalHigh = 0;
    oWrite.Offset       = 0;
    oWrite.OffsetHigh   = 0;

    assert(oWrite.hEvent);

    result = WriteFile(hComm, pckt, length, NULL, &oWrite);
    if (result == FALSE) {
       errCode = GetLastError();
     if (errCode != ERROR_IO_PENDING) printf("Error! Setting CommMask\n");
    }

    dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(oWrite.hEvent, INFINITE);

    switch(dwWaitResult) {
      case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        printf("No Wait. Send complete.\n");
        break;
      case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        printf("Wait Timeout.\n");
        break;
      case WAIT_FAILED:
        printf("Wait Failed.\n");
        break;
      case WAIT_ABANDONED:
        printf("Wait Abandoned.\n");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    CloseHandle(oWrite.hEvent);
    return 0;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int recvpckt(HANDLE hComm, unsigned char * pckt)
{
    BOOL result;
    DWORD dwWaitResult, errCode, BytesRead = 0;
    OVERLAPPED oRead = { 0 };

    oRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (oRead.hEvent == NULL) return FALSE; // Error creating OL event handle.

    // Initialize the rest of the OVERLAPPED structure to zero.
    oRead.Internal     = 0;
    oRead.InternalHigh = 0;
    oRead.Offset       = 0;
    oRead.OffsetHigh   = 0;

    assert(oRead.hEvent);

    result = ReadFile(hComm, pckt, 2048, &BytesRead, &oRead);
    if (result == FALSE) {
        errCode = GetLastError();
      if (errCode != ERROR_IO_PENDING) printf("nError! Setting CommMask\n");
    }

    dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(oRead.hEvent, INFINITE);

    switch (dwWaitResult) {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        printf("Received: ");
        if (BytesRead > 0) {
          printf("%d byte(s) -- ", BytesRead);
        }
        else printf("Nothing\n");
        break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        printf("RX Timeout.\n");
        break;
    case WAIT_FAILED:
        printf("RX Wait Failed: \n");
        if (BytesRead > 0) {
          printf("%d byte(s) -- ", BytesRead);
        }
        else printf("Nothing\n");
        break;
    case WAIT_ABANDONED:
        printf("RX Abandoned.\n");
        return FALSE;
    default:
        break;
    }

    CloseHandle(oRead.hEvent);
    return BytesRead;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int args(int argc, char * argv[], char * port) 
{
  static int i;
  i = atoi(argv[1]);
  sprintf(port, "\\\\.\\COM%d", i);
  return i;
};
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
char *TimeNow(char * TimeString)
{
  SYSTEMTIME st;
  GetSystemTime(&st);
  sprintf(TimeString, "%.2d:%.2d:%.2d.%.3d",
    st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
  return TimeString;
}
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    HANDLE hPort;
    int len;
    unsigned idx=0, portNum;
    unsigned char TXBUF[2048], RXBUF[2048], port[64], timeString[14], SendMe=0;

    if (argc > 1) portNum = args(argc, argv, port);
    else 
    {
      printf("Please identify the serial port number to open.\n");
      exit(0);
    }
    SetConsoleTitle(port); // To specify serial port number on open 

    hPort = CreateFile(port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL); 

    ConfigureSerialPort(hPort);
    if (hPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Error in openning serial port\n");
        exit(0); // No point in going on if serial port didn't open
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Serial Port %d Open at %s\n", portNum, TimeNow(timeString));
    }

    while (1) {
        TXBUF[0] = (SendMe++)%256;
        printf("Sending 0x%.2X at %s ", TXBUF[0], TimeNow(timeString));
        sendpckt(hPort, 1, TXBUF);

        len = recvpckt(hPort, RXBUF);
        if (len > 0) {
           printf("%s RCVD[%d byte(s)]: ", TimeNow(timeString), len);
         for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
         {
            printf("%d:0x%.2X ", idx+1, RXBUF[idx]);
         }
          printf("\n");
        }

        SleepEx(1000, TRUE); // How often to send data out TX buffer
    }
    printf("Error: %d", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(hPort); // Close the serial port
}
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
```

Comment: OVERLAPPED oRead = { 0 }; does initialize the oRead structure to 0