# Windows Serial port throughput issues

Tags: c#, winapi, serial-port

I'm using Win32 serial port APIs in a Console app to communicate with a board at high baud rates (3.6 MBaud)
The board has a 16KB internal log buffer that needs to be continuously read by the Windows host app. The board can send data in packets with a max packet length of 512 Bytes.
Everything works fine except the receive part (using ReadFile()) seems to have an inherent delay of ~15 ms that limits the max data throughput to ~33KB/s regardless of the baud rate used, which causes the board's internal log buffer to eventually overflow because Windows can not empty it fast enough.
The above was verified on a scope with a loop that sends a ping command to the board. Windows starts receiving data a couple of microseconds after the end of the ping and the ping response measures ~160 uSec on the scope, while ReadFile() for the ping response always return after 15 ms.
I'm not sure if there's a way to speed things up on Windows side, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Sample code below.

```
#region Native structures
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DCB
{
    public int DCBlength;           //  The length of the DCB structure (in bytes)
    public int BaudRate;            //  Baud rate setting
    public int flags;
    public ushort wReserved;        //  Keep
    public ushort XonLim;           //  When the characters in the receiving Buffer decrease by the number of characters specified by XonLim, Xon characters are sent and the other party can continue sending.
    public ushort XoffLim;          //  When the receiving Buffer reaches the number of characters specified by XoffLim, Xoff characters are sent to let the other party stop sending.
    public byte ByteSize;           //  Data bit setting
    public byte Parity;             //  Setting of parity bit: 0-4=no,odd,even,mark,space
    public byte StopBits;           //  Stop bit setting: 0,1,2 = 1, 1.5, 2
    public char XonChar;            //  Xon characters
    public char XoffChar;           //  Xoff characters 
    public char ErrorChar;          //  When Parity Check is wrong, the characters to be replaced 
    public char EofChar;            //  EOF substitute character 
    public char EvtChar;            //  Event trigger character
    public ushort wReserved1;       //  Keep
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct COMMTIMEOUTS
{
    public int ReadIntervalTimeout;
    public int ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier;
    public int ReadTotalTimeoutConstant;
    public int WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier;
    public int WriteTotalTimeoutConstant;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct COMSTAT
{
    public int flags;
    public int cbInQue;
    public int cbOutQue;
}
#endregion

public class Win32Serial
{
    IntPtr hSerial;
    byte ParityBits;
    byte StopBitsCount;
    byte ByteBits;
    string winPortName;
    int GENERIC_RW = 0x3 << 30;                 // GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE
    int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    int ERROR_IO_PENDING = 0x3E5;
    IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE = (IntPtr)(-1);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFileA(
        string lpFileName,
        int dwDesiredAccess,
        int dwShareMode,
        IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
        int dwCreationDisposition,
        int dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr hTemplateFile
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool ReadFile(
        IntPtr hFile,                   // handle to file
        byte[] lpBuffer,                // data buffer
        int nNumberOfBytesToRead,       // number of bytes to read
        ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead,    // number of bytes read
        IntPtr lpOverlapped             // overlapped buffer
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool WriteFile(
        IntPtr hFile,                   // handle to file
        byte[] lpBuffer,                // data buffer
        int nNumberOfBytesToWrite,      // number of bytes to write
        ref int lpNumberOfBytesWritten, // number of bytes written
        IntPtr lpOverlapped             // overlapped buffer
        );


    public Win32Serial(string pName, int baud, Parity parity, byte bits, StopBits sBits)
    {
        PortName = pName;
        winPortName = pName;
        hSerial = INVALID_HANDLE;
        if (PortName.Length > 4)
        {
            winPortName = @"\\.\" + pName;
        }

        BaudRate = baud;

        if (parity == Parity.None) ParityBits = 0;
        else if (parity == Parity.Odd) ParityBits = 1;
        else if (parity == Parity.Even) ParityBits = 2;
        else if (parity == Parity.Mark) ParityBits = 3;
        else if (parity == Parity.Space) ParityBits = 4;

        ByteBits = bits;

        if (sBits == StopBits.None) StopBitsCount = 0;
        else if (sBits == StopBits.One) StopBitsCount = 0;
        else if (sBits == StopBits.OnePointFive) StopBitsCount = 1;
        else if (sBits == StopBits.Two) StopBitsCount = 2;
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        try
        {
            hSerial = CreateFileA(winPortName, GENERIC_RW, 0, (IntPtr)0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, (IntPtr)0);
            if (hSerial != INVALID_HANDLE)
            {
                SetTimeouts();
                DCB dcbParams = new DCB();
                dcbParams.DCBlength = Marshal.SizeOf(dcbParams);
                GetCommState(hSerial, ref dcbParams);

                dcbParams.BaudRate = BaudRate;
                dcbParams.ByteSize = ByteBits;
                dcbParams.flags = 1;
                dcbParams.Parity = ParityBits;
                dcbParams.StopBits = StopBitsCount;

                SetCommState(hSerial, ref dcbParams);
                DiscardInBuffer();
                DiscardOutBuffer();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            hSerial = INVALID_HANDLE;
        }
    }

    private void SetTimeouts()
    {
        try
        {
            if (hSerial != INVALID_HANDLE)
            {
                COMMTIMEOUTS comPortTimeouts = new COMMTIMEOUTS();
                GetCommTimeouts(hSerial, ref comPortTimeouts);

                comPortTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
                comPortTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = ReadTimeout;
                comPortTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
                comPortTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
                comPortTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = WriteTimeout;

                SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, ref comPortTimeouts);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }


    public int Read(byte[] buf, int offset, int lenToRead, ref int readLen)
    {
        if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE)
        {
            IoError();
            return (-1);
        }

        byte[] readBuf = new byte[lenToRead];
        readLen = 0;

        // DEBUG
        ConsolePrint(String.Format("{0,8:D}", timeControl.ElapsedMs()) + "    ReadFile() started\n");

        if (!ReadFile(hSerial, readBuf, lenToRead, ref readLen, (IntPtr)0))
        {
            IoError();
            return (-2);
        }

        // DEBUG. This measures 15ms from the last call to timeControl.ElapsedMs()
        ConsolePrint(String.Format("{0,8:D}", timeControl.ElapsedMs()) + "    ReadFile() completed\n");

        if ((readLen > 0) && (readLen <= lenToRead))
        {
            Array.Copy(readBuf, 0, buf, offset, readLen);
            return (readLen);
        }
        IoError();
        return (-3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `SerialPort` class?

Comment: Initially I did try but ran into so many problems. https://sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318481/c-net-wrapper-for-serial-port-win32-comm-api

Comment: I've been using serial ports on PC's sine the days of 8086.  The Microsoft serial port has always been slow using straight reads.  I've always used Event successfully.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Comment: It looks like the issue is in the Windows driver itself.
Replacing the read function above with a loop that query the number of available bytes (by calling ClearCommError()) until the required number of bytes is available, still consumes 15ms.
What's weird is that out of all the calls to ClearCommError() in that loop, just a single one of them consume the entire 15ms, and it happens at random, while returning number of available bytes = 0

Comment: This is the issue that the [Handshake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.handshake?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) property of the [SerialPort Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) is meant to deal with.

Comment: What about setting the [SerialPort.ReadBufferSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) to a sufficiently large value?

Comment: @user246821 The board fills its internal log buffer but never sends data unless it's asked to by the host (Windows) app and as such, the Windows serial port RX buffer can never overflow since the board will only send a max of 512-byte packet in response to each request from the host. The issue is that the host cannot read the board fast enough because of the 15 mSec delay of each read.

Comment: _The issue is that the host cannot read the board fast enough because of the 15 mSec delay of each read_: It seems that you misidentified the issue. The issue is that you haven't yet learned how to properly write a program in C# that works with the device. Furthermore, you haven't provided information about the device such as manufacturer, model number, and URL to the documentation such that anyone else may be able to assist you.

Comment: It seems that the protocol written in the comment (pair of write:request command,read:response data) and the source code presented in the question do not match. Also, isn't it a bad system design to try to make that mechanism work at 3.6 Mega bps on Windows, which is not a real-time OS? It is better to implement a streaming mode that does not require a request command for each packet when the device side sends data, or to build a dedicated device driver that implements a request/response protocol within the device driver instead of using a general-purpose serial port. It seems to be good.

Comment: @kunif yes, Windows is not an RTOS, but a machine with 64GB RAM running at 4.6GHz should handle 3.6Mbaud serial port with ease, especially if it's not running anything else.  Also, even on Windows, the serial port is likely serviced by DMA so it will never drop data as long as the system is not saturated. The fact that the call to the read function always take 15ms regardless of the read data length is kind of fishy. The same behavior was also observed at lower baud rates.

Comment: Your program uses the serial port synchronously, so why not try using it asynchronously? The ReadFile API is always issued, and when data arrives at the device driver, an event notification is received from the OS, so check the completion status at that time. If you can't change the hardware or device drivers, that's probably the least you can do. [Synchronous and Asynchronous I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o), [Asynchronous Serial I/O on Win32 -- How To Create An Alert Event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59867506/9014308)

Comment: ReadFile() blocks until requested data is read or the operation timesout. I would imagine that ReadFile() waits on an event from the serial port then when the required data is received, it returns to the caller.
Using the serial port asynchronously from the app is useful if I want to do other stuff until the required data is received. This is not a concern, plus the call to ReadFile() is made from a dedicated read thread anyway. Also, I don't think the issues is specific to ReadFile(); as noted above, calling ClearCommError() to get the number of available bytes exhibits the same 15ms delay.

Comment: In reality, you are experiencing delays that you did not expect, so instead of sticking to your current method or expected behavior, why not try some other methods that are easy to experiment with?
You haven't revealed what manufacturer and model your device is, and the source code you've provided isn't complete, so the most anyone else can do is provide a few hints.