What would be the correct way to implement an asynchronous read operation in C# regarding tasks and avoiding busy-wait loops (for Windows)
Background:
I am attempting to implement my own version of the System.IO.Ports SerialPort .Net class since I am not satisfied with the way it handles timeouts in Windows, I would like to have more control of the underlying logic. This means I would be using the winapi ReadFile and Writefile. Naturally, async-await support would be great for such a thing.
The problem I am facing now is how to actually implement the asynchronous read/write operations.
The options I have figured so far:

running of a Task and a synchronous Read/Write inside. The problem with this is that it can't facilitate a cancellation token.

Use of IOCP with the OVERLAPPED structure and then a Task that has an actual busy-wait loop inside with some delay that waits for the IOCP signal:


public async Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (_handle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Serial port is not open");
    }

    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[count];
    var overlapped = new OVERLAPPED { hEvent = CreateEvent(IntPtr.Zero, true, false, null) };
    uint bytesRead = 0;


    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {

        if (!ReadFile(_handle, tempBuffer, (uint)count, out bytesRead, ref overlapped))
        {
            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (error != 997) // ERROR_IO_PENDING
            {
                throw new IOException($"ReadFile failed with error {error}", new Win32Exception(error));
            }
        }
        while (true)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                CancelIo(_handle);
                break;
            }

            if (GetOverlappedResult(_handle, ref overlapped, out bytesRead, false))
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5); // Reduce CPU usage
        }
    }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

    Array.Copy(tempBuffer, 0, buffer, offset, bytesRead);
    return (int)bytesRead;
}

Is there a way to avoid using the while(true) wait loop here?

"Use of IOCP with the OVERLAPPED structure and then a Task that has an actual busy-wait loop inside with some delay that waits for the IOCP signal:" - This is almost how you're meant to do it (but ditch the busy-wait loop and use a TaskCompletionSource - while using Task.Run is just disguising the fact you aren't using the OS' async/overlapped support) but first-things-first, are you 100% certain that your UART driver supports overlapped IO like this?

See this QA: it's someone doing the same thing as you:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/59867506/159145

Actualy no, not really sure about that at all, and judging by your question it seems that I am pretty ignorant about what overlapped IO means.
Since I am going to use this for Modbus communication as a master, I haven't really thought of more complicated cases

If you really want the same kind of detailed control as the win32api, it would be easier to use a library like this ebraminio/PInvokeSerialPort, or to create a library in C++ with your own method/property/event API in C++/CLI and make it usable from C#.

Usually, at the actual IO layer you don't get to use async; you usually instead spin up a TaskCompletionSource, and attach whatever callbacks the IO API offers - triggering the [Try]SetResult or [Try]SetException APIs on the TCS, offering up the TCS's .Task as the return value. You also need to consider subscribing to the cancellation token's event, to try to trigger a cancellation through the IO layer.
